# How to differentiate errors in Elixir's `with` macro?

Tags: elixir

Often I have code that uses the `with` macro to ensure all the required data is available before proceeding, but I want to have more fine-grained errors to determine precisely why it failed.

Using an example from the documentation:

```
with {:ok, width} <- Map.fetch(opts, :width),
     {:ok, height} <- Map.fetch(opts, :height) do
  {:ok, width * height}
else
  :error ->
    {:error, :wrong_data}
end
```

I would like to know whether the `width` or the `height` is missing in the error tuple.

My attempt is to use defaults:

```
with {:ok, width} <- Map.fetch(opts, :width, {:error, :missing_width}),
     {:ok, height} <- Map.fetch(opts, :height, {:error, :missing_height}) do
  {:ok, width * height}
else
  {:error, reason} = error -> error
end
```

But this doesn't feel particularly elegant. Is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: It should be noted that `Map.fetch/3` that I wrote above unfortunately does not exist. You can use `Map.get/3` with a default but then you lose the `:ok` return tuple and thus can't pattern match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your `with` lines on descriptive tuples and still assert on the return you want, this will then allow you to discern/provide feedback where the error was.

```
with(
     {_, {:ok, width}} <- {:width, Map.fetch(opts, :width)},
     {_, {:ok, height}} <- {:height, Map.fetch(opts, :height)}
  ) do

  {:ok, width * height}

else
  {what, :error} ->
    {:error, {what, :wrong_data}}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little specific to the example you provided, but you could always create a wrapper module/function.

```
defmodule MapHelpers do
  def fetch_number(%{} = map, field) do
    case Map.fetch(map, field) do
      {:ok, val} when is_number(val) ->
        {:ok, val}

      {:ok, val} -> 
        {:error, "#{to_string(val)} in attribute #{to_string(field)} is not a number"}

      :error ->
        {:error, "#{to_string(field)} is not defined"}
    end
  end
end
```

Then your code everywhere else becomes a lot simpler:

```
with {:ok, width} <- MapHelpers.fetch_number(opts, :width),
     {:ok, height} <- MapHelpers.fetch_number(opts, :height) do
    {:ok, width * height}
end
```

This way you don't have to define an else block and you have reusable code for fetching numbers from maps.